# How to remove the focus from Notification area so that another click can be performed?

Tags: testcomplete

In my tests I have managed to right-click on my Application icon in the Notification area and work with the menu that appears as a result of this action.
The next step is ,I again need to click on the app icon in notification area and select another option from the menu.

As a result of my first click, the menu is still open when it attempts the second click.
How can i make the menu disappear before my second click?

I am using Testcomplete9 and jscript.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can anyone have a look at this please.Thanks

Comment: How do you usually close the opened menu in your app (without using TestComplete)? You can record this action and the menu will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simulating the Escape key stroke before the second click:

```
Sys.Keys("[Esc]");
```